# No provisioning profiles installed error on Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to debug my Xamarin Studio project on iPhone.
I did all the steps for creating provisioning profile file on [this document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/).
So I have created the provisioning profile
but I cannot install this to Xcode.

On Xcode when I check Window menu / Devices > iPhone > Show Provisioning Profiles
it says `No provisioning profiles installed`

Although I have double clicked or added the file and rebooted
there is nothing happen and its not seen  in this window.

How can I fix this?

Note :
I'm trying with iPhone 4S and running IOS 7.0 on it.

Comment: In xcode go to preferences=>general=>account=>view details then click on download all. The profiles will be downloaded. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/obtain_certificates_and_provisioning_profiles.html

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work.

Comment: After downloading the profiles create a sample hello world application in xcode and run it on the device, the profiles will be downloaded on the device.

Comment: I did but my profile file, still not seen on the profiles list on Xcode.
Yet I tried to debug on Xamarin Studio. And it gets this error :
error MT1006: Could not install the application ‘…iOS.app' on the device  : AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8000067 (kAMDAPIInternalError).

Comment: To your new problem. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32191/unable-to-install-unified-64-bit-converted-code-on-to-an-ipad-1-ios-5-1-1

Comment: Okey I have changed the ARM64 to ARM7 on IOS Build options for my IOS 7 but it gets permission error while I'm trying to debug on iPhone : error MT1006: Could not install the application '....iOS.app' on the device: Permission Error (error: 0xe800000a).
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP

Comment: Try to clean your solution, build it again and run.@mrbengi

Comment: Okey cleaned, also closed and reopen but still have the same error

Comment: By the way, I have a warning, my application's icon set has unassigned child on images.xcassets (I didn't have set all icons and so have missing icons).

Comment: I have updated Xamarin Studio, now I build with no error or warning but still have the same permission error when trying to debug on iPhone.